# How fast can one change the IT organization to a Business Game Changer

Tags: strategy, portfolio-management

There are five stages of an IT organization from a business stakeholders' view:

1. Cost center
2. Service Provider
3. IT Partner
4. Business Peer
5. Business Game Changer

(Source: CIO Magazine 2013 State of the CIO Survey)

If the company is between first and second change, is it possible to move directly to stage 5?

*Comment: Maybe in an growed organization it is a slow process from 1 to 5 that every company has to go?*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to any Project Management concepts, processes, or tools. 

Comment: Too many buzzwords. Managerial noise detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving directly is based on the perceived trust of the shareholders and executives.

The speed at which you can change this relationship, totally depends on the cultural willingness of the organisation to firstly acknowledge they want to change, and then to follow this through with a committed approach.

Its going to ultimately boil down to the working relationship and trust level between the stakeholders and IT.  Welcome to the **human element**.